# Applying fancybox on future elements?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Is it possible to apply fancybox(or any lightbox alternative) on elements that are loaded by hquery's load() ? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're loaded elements are classed as "loadedElement"

```
$(".loadedElement").live("load", function() {
    // Implement lightbox code
});
```

Or if you want to implement that lightbox *before* the images have finished loading, change "load" to "ready"

Answer (score 2):

Check out [jQuery Live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to bind to elements added by jQuery.

> Description: Attach a handler to the
>   event for all elements which match the
>   current selector, now or in the
>   future.